# Password after factory reset

Tags: ipad, password

After factory reset, my iPad asked for a 4 digit password, when I used the old password it doesn't recognise it anymore. Now the devise is locked, how do I find out the new password?

Comment: There shouldn’t be a passcode after a factory reset. How exactly did you reset the device, did you disable Find My iPhone first, are you sure it‘s not remotely managed by your employer?

Comment: My colleagues reset it before returning to me. I believe she just did the factory reset on the ipad. it's not remotely managed devise.